# LINQ: get nested arrays based on a groupby?

Tags: c#, linq, nested

Suppose I have this simple object definition:

```
public class Item
{
    public int section { get; set; }
    public string item { get; set; }
}
```

I have some data in a single-depth array. This is JSON, which would be converted to C# objects via Json.NET:

```
[
  {
    "section": 0,
    "item": "Hello!"
  },
  { 
    "section": 1,
    "item": "First Steps"
  },
  {
    "section": 1,
    "item": "How to Ask for Help"
  },
  {
    "section": 2,
    "item": "Your First Program"
  },
  {
    "section": 2,
    "item": "The Code"
  },
  {
    "section": 2,
    "item": "How It Works"
  },
  {
    "section": 3,
    "item": "Where To Go From Here"
  }
]
```

Using Entity Framework or some other method, I have arrived at a simple list of these objects as stated above, contained within a `var` variable.

Now what I want to do is get the same list, but where each section is grouped as an array within the outer array. For example, the JSON of what I want looks like this:

```
[
  [
    {
      "section": 0,
      "item": "Hello!"
    }
  ],
  [
    { 
      "section": 1,
      "item": "First Steps"
    },
    {
      "section": 1,
      "item": "How to Ask for Help"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "section": 2,
      "item": "Your First Program"
    },
    {
      "section": 2,
      "item": "The Code"
    },
    {
      "section": 2,
      "item": "How It Works"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "section": 3,
      "item": "Where To Go From Here"
    }
  ]
]
```

My initial thought was to do something with a LINQ query using the `groupby` statement but I don't think this is what I'm looking for - `groupby` seems to be analogous to the SQL version so it can only be used for aggregate operations.

The only other option I have found so far is to use a LINQ query to get a list of all of the sections:

```
var allSections = (from x in myData select x.section).Distinct();
```

...and then iterate through those IDs and manually build the array:

```
List<List<Item>> mainList = new List<List<Item>>();
foreach (int thisSection in allSections.ToArray()) 
{
    List<Item> thisSectionsItems = (from x in myData where x.section == thisSection select x).ToList();
    mainList.Add(thisSectionsItems);
}
return mainList;
```

This should result in a proper enumerable that I can feed into JSON.NET and get the expected result, but this seems inefficient.

Is there a more LINQ-ish, or at least more efficient, way to split the items into groups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly achieve this with `.GroupBy()`

```
var grouped = items
    .GroupBy(x => x.section)    // group by section
    .Select(x => x.ToArray())   // build the inner arrays
    .ToArray();                 // return collection of arrays as an array
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.